# What problems are caused by nested Blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

When using GCD, I sometimes use Blocks inside Blocks.
What problems will occur when doing this, other than retain cycles?

Please explain in detail. Will the outer block copy the whole memory, including local variables, and the inner block copy every local variable that the outer block just copied, or will the local variables be in the inner block only? What problems will occur then?

Comment: I think this is off-topic for StackOverflow.  It might be better for you to post your code here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jcm: You seem to have commented on the wrong question. There's no code here.

Comment: I meant that it would be better match for the codereview site.

Comment: This question is a bit broad. Perhaps you can show a concrete example that you have problems with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a block copies "virtually" all reachable local vars of a program. Of course this is optimized by the compiler. Only that variables are copied that are used inside the block.

Second: They are copied with the state they have, when the block is defined. This means exactly: When the statement that defines the block literal is executed. (The statement with `^{…}`, not the statement with `…()`)

With an example it is easier to understand:

```
int outerInnerVar = 1;
int innerVar = 1;
__block int uncapturedVar = 1;
void (^outer)(void) =
^{
    NSLog(@"outer: %ld", (long)outerInnerVar);
    uncapturedVar = 3;
    void (^inner)(void) =
    ^{
        NSLog(@"inner: %ld", (long)outerInnerVar);
        NSLog(@"inner: %ld", (long)innerVar);
        NSLog(@"inner: %ld", (long)uncapturedVar);
    };
    uncapturedVar = 4;
    inner();
};
outerInnerVar = 2;
innerVar = 2;
uncapturedVar = 2;
outer();
```

**outerInnerVar**

The outer block captures `outerInnerVar` with a value of 1. The inner block literal captures does nothing, because it is not executed.  This is done in the last line. But since the outer block has captured `outerInnerVar` into its closure, the now executed inner block definition is executed with `outerInnerVar`having the value of 1. Therefore the inner block captures `outerInnerVar` with the value of 1, too.

→ You get two logs with 1 for `outerInnerVar`.

**innerVar**

Maybe you expect a different result for `innerVar`. But it is used *inside* the outer block, because it is used inside the inner block, which is inside the outer block. So the outer block put `innerVar` into its ( the outer) closure, too. The result is the same:

→ You get a log with 1 for `innerVar`. (Which in reality is another `outerInnerVar`.)

**uncapturedVar**

`uncapturedVar` is obviously not in the closure of the outer block. So it is quite clear that we will not log it with a value of 1. But with 2, 3 or 4?

`uncapturedVar` is a block *variable*. This defines the behavior of it, not the block. Consequently it is a block variable inside all nested (and consecutive) blocks. So the last state of the variable before executing the block itself (not its definition) will be find.

→ You get a log with 4 for `uncapturedVar`.

Personally I would expect a different behavior of `innerVar`. But I think that capturing it silently by the outer block is reasonable.

When the copies are done physically is an implementation detail.

Comment: "First of all a block copies "virtually" the whole state of a program." Blocks only capture local variables.

Comment: This is not related to the type of vars, but to the amount. I clarified this.